Is the equality of subgroups of a free group detectable via a *set* of test groups?
Question. Is there a set of groups $\mathcal{T}$ that separate subgroups in the following sense? If $G$ is any free group and $U,V \subseteq G$ are subgroups such that $f(U) = f(V)$ for all homomorphisms $f : G \to T$ with $T \in \mathcal{T}$, then $U = V$.
I have the same question for (free) abelian groups.
Context. I am working on a project which analyses natural transformations into the functor $\mathrm{Sub} : \mathbf{Grp} \to \mathbf{Set}$ that maps a group to its set of subgroups and every homomorphism to the image operation. If the above statement is true, $[F,\mathrm{Sub}]$ would be equivalent to a set whenever $F$ is a functor that preserves epis. And this would be very convenient.
Notice that the corresponding question is of course easy to answer when working with vector spaces over $K$, here we just take $\mathcal{T} = \{K\}$. Linear forms are enough to detect the equality of subspaces. For finitely generated free abelian groups, $\mathcal{T} = \{\mathbb{Z}\}$ also does the job, but not for arbitrary free abelian groups, see Does the dual group of a free abelian group separate subgroups?. Does maybe $\{\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}^2\}$ work?
I am kind of unsure what to believe here. On the one hand, there might be strong set-theoretical obstructions which prevent $\mathcal{T}$ to be a (small) set. On the other hand, it works for vector spaces, which can also have any dimension. Either way, I think that the proof will involve some set theory, hence the tag.

If $U, V$ are finitely generated then you can use finite quotients.

My inclination here would be to try something like $\mathcal{T} = { F_2 }$ since already all the f.g. free groups embed into $F_2$, which seems like a promising amount of "room."

This is just an idea, but perhaps for a given $\mathcal{T}$, one can let $U=G$ be the free group on $\kappa^+$ many generators where $\kappa=\sup_{T\in\mathcal{T}}|T|$. Then let $V$ be generated by ${e_je_k^{-1}e_ie_ke_j^{-1}:i<j<k<\kappa^+}$. Then $f(V)=f(U)$ for all $f:G\to T$ with $T\in\mathcal{T}$, but I believe $U\neq V$. In particular, I think $e_0\notin V$. (I haven’t figured out a proof though.)

Update: I think I managed to complete the answer to show that such a set can't exist.
This isn't an answer but we can reduce to the case that $\mathcal{T}$ consists of a single free group. If such a small set $\mathcal{T}$ existed, then without loss of generality we may assume that all $T \in \mathcal{T}$ are free since for all $T \in \mathcal{T}$ we can choose a free group $G_{T}$ along with a surjection $G_{T} \to T$ and if $G$ were any free group, $U \neq V$ subgroups of $G$ and $f$ a map that separates them, then we can factor f through $G_T$, and this map must also separate $U$ and $V$. Now I argue that we may take $\mathcal{T}$ to consist of a single free group without loss of generality. Since $\mathcal{T}$ is a small set of small groups, its disjoint union is a small set. Taking $S$ to be any small set of strictly greater cardinality, every free group in $\mathcal{T}$ can be embedded into $F(S)$ (the free group on $S$). If $\mathcal{T}$ has the required property, it is easy to see that just $F(S)$ will work.

(added later)
Let $G = F(2^{S})$, and let $ \{ g_{\alpha} \mid \alpha \in 2^{S} \}$ be a generating set for $G$. Let $U = \langle g_{\alpha}g_{\beta}^{-1}g_{\emptyset}g_{\beta}g_{\alpha}^{-1} \mid \alpha, \beta \in 2^{S} \setminus \{ \emptyset \}, \alpha \neq \beta \rangle$. Now let me prove a lemma.
Lemma: If $W$ is a set of elements in $G \setminus \{ 1\}$ such that no word in $W$ contains $g_{\emptyset}$, then $ g_{\emptyset} \not\in \langle wg_{\emptyset}w^{-1} \mid w \in W \ \rangle $.
Proof: Consider an arbitrary element generated by $W$, say $(w_1g_{\emptyset}^{s_1}w_1^{-1})(w_2g_{\emptyset}^{s_2}w_2^{-1}) \cdots (w_ng_{\emptyset}^{s_n}w_n^{-1})$ where the $s_i$ are non-zero integers and $w_i \neq w_{i+1}$ for all $i < n$. Once we reduce the "middle" terms $ w_i^{-1} w_{i+1} $ which we know are non-zero, the word is now in reduced form and can't be reduced further. But note that the first letter can't be $g_{\emptyset}$, which proves the lemma.
Now the lemma can be applied to show that $ g_{\emptyset} \not\in U $. Let $V = \langle g_{\emptyset}, U \rangle$ and note that for any homomorphism $f : G \to F(S)$ there must exist $\alpha, \beta \in 2^{S} \setminus \{ \emptyset \}$ such that $\alpha \neq \beta$ but $f(g_{\alpha}) = f(g_{\beta})$. This implies that $f(U) = f(V)$. This gives the required contradiction.

Thanks! How do you prove $U \neq V$? I think this is actually the main part, the rest seems to be rather formal and will also work for abelian groups or any algebraic structures for that matter where $F(S)$ has the same cardinality as $S$, and subalgebras of free algebras are free. But for vector spaces (over a countable field), we cannot conclude $U \neq V$ apparently. Does it work for abelian groups?

Right, I concluded by noticing that any concatenation of two of the generators of $U$ is a reduced word since looking at the point where two generators meet, $g_{\emptyset}g_{\alpha}$, we can't reduce further (and furthermore, we can't reduce within each generator) and this reduced word is certainly not $g_{\emptyset}$. This sort of argument is pretty particular to groups.

Hmm. But what about the inverse of a generator. Let me just write $a$ instead of $g_a$. Then $U$ does contain $a b' 0 (c b' 0)' = a c'$. And then it also contains $0$. So it doesn't work?

You are right, I was too hasty. I guess I should delete my answer

Maybe you can just delete the ending, and change the first sentence. Then at least we have the reduction to $\mathcal{T}={F(S)}$.

Excellent! Did you follow the comment by David Gao or did you find this example indenpedently? In the first case I would suggest to give him credit in the post.

I found it independently, I saw the comment only afterwards
